# flask_marshmallow prevent loading new entities, but allow loading existing ones

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

Marshmallow schemas have a `dump_only` option which prevents deserializing things in that attribute during a `load` event.

For example:

```
class UserSerializationSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = User

    messages = fields.Nested(MessageSerializationSchema, dump_only=True)
```

We want to let marshmallow load orm objects in these fields if they already exist, but we do NOT want to allow creating new objects by deserializing. Flask-marshmallow does load existing objects without creating new ones, for example the following dict when `load` is run would create a new user with the specified `email` and associate it with an existing message with the `uid` 1:

```
{ 
    'email': 'email@email.com',
    'messages': {
        'uid': 1
    }
  }
```

Unfortunately, the above functionality doesn't work when `dump_only` is `True` on the field. Is it possible to tell marshmallow to allow associating with existing objects, but not to create new objects via deserialization?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not.